# How can I get codepipeline execution id in cdk at runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am using AWS CDK to deploy a codepipeline. It also has a notification rule which notify when the pipeline fails. I need to put the codepipeline job URL in the notify message in order for people to open the piepline easily.

In cloudformation, I have to put below configuation to compute the URL:

```
Targets:
        - Arn: !Ref SNSTopicNotification
          Id: piplineID
          InputTransformer:
            InputPathsMap:
              pipeline: "$.detail.pipeline"
              executionId: "$.detail.execution-id"
              region: "$.region"
            InputTemplate: !Sub |
              "Pipeline <pipeline> failed"
"https://<region>.console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/codepipeline/pipelines/<pipeline>/executions/<executionId>/timeline?region=<region>"
```

the key is using `$.detail.xxx` to reference the value at runtime. How can I achieve this in CDK?